# How to calculate the lat/lng of a point a certain distance from another point?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

consider having a circle on map with center GLatLng (A) and a radius (r) in meters.

[image]

How to calculate the GLatLng at position B? Assuming that r is parallel to the equator.

Getting the radius when A and B is given is trivial using the GLatLng.distanceFrom() method - but doing it the other way around not so.

to summarize, given Lat/lng of Point A and R in meters, I need to get Lat/Lng of Point B. direction is not important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is take the original point and compute the distance for one degree to the east or west. That will give you the distance per degree along that line of latitude. Then divide r by the distance per degree and it will tell you how many degrees B is to the east or west.